# How to change access to a particular folder of google drive using node.js?

Tags: node.js, api, google-drive-api

I'm learning about `google drive API` for node.js. I'm curious to know **how can I change access type of a particular file/folder of google drive in the node.js?**

Means let's suppose I've got a folder named `Batman` in a google drive. Inside the batman folder, there are 3 files, one file's access type is `public` and other's access type is `private`. So, how can I iterate through the batman folder to change `access type` of the sub-files?

Code:(It gets the 10 file names from the google drive)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');


 const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

 const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

 // Load client secrets from a local file.
 fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
 authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
  });



 function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

// Check if we have previously stored a token.
fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
callback(oAuth2Client);
});
}

function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: 'offline',
  scope: SCOPES,
});
console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});
rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
  rl.close();
  oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
    // Store the token to disk for later program executions
    fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
    });
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
});
  }

function listFiles(auth) {
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
drive.files.list({
  pageSize: 10,
  fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
}, (err, res) => {
  if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
  const files = res.data.files;
  if (files.length) {
    console.log('Files:');
    files.map((file) => {
       console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('No files found.');
  }
  console.log(files)
});
 }
```

Comment: If you know the `id` of your folder, you can list files specifying in the  [`q` parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files) `'id' in parents`, to list only the file in the folder.

Comment: @ziganotschka thanks a lot for your response, yeah I would definitely do that, and it would be really helpful for me if you could tell that how to change access type?

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors you have to take into consideration to change the access type of a certain file/folder. [Share files, folders and drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing) states all the details and parameters that can be changed. For doing it programmatically. Follow the next steps:

### 1) List files:

List all the files in the specific folder you want to change using the `q` parameter, unfortunately, there is a bug with the [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client), in which the `q` parameter will not return the files. The bug is reported [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1957), so you could comment or give a thumb up to let know Google you also have that issue. As a workaround I recommend you using axios.

```
const queryFoldersWithAxios = async () => {
  const params = {
    q: "'<YOUR_FOLDER_ID>' in parents",
    fields: "files(name,id)"
  };
  const headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
  return await axios.get("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files", {params, headers})
}
```

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22%27%3Cyour-folder-id%3E%27%20in%20parents%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22files(id%2Cname)%22%7D)

### 2) Create Permissions

You can create a new permission by just passing the file id.

```
const createPermissions = async (drive, fileId) => {
  // Return the Promise result after completing its task
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const body = {
      "role": "reader",
      "type": "anyone"
    };
    return drive.permissions.create({ 
      fileId,
      resource: body 
    },(err, results) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(results));
  });
}
```

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%22your-file-id%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22role%22%3A%22writer%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22anyone%22%7D%7D)

### 3) List File permissions

You can verify all permissions in a file by listing its permissions and you can even get the ids of the permissions.

```
const listFilePermissions = async (drive, fileId) => {
  // Return the Promise result after completing its task
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return drive.permissions.list({ fileId }, {
      "fields": 'permissions'
    },(err, results) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(results))
  });
}
```

- [Permissions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%22your-file-id%22%7D)

### Notice

Take the second step as examples of what you could do, please read [Share files, folders and drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing) to learn all the possible combinations you could do. Also, you can play with the ***Try this API*** to test the permissions before implementing them in code.

Comment: Created spreadsheet by default is public, anyone with the link can access the file. How can I restrict it programatically?